# lvcreate - Volume group has insufficient free space

Tags: lvm

I get this when I try to create a logical volume:

```
Volume group "MorArchy" has insufficient free space (511 extents): 19456 required.
```

I'm using this command:

```
lvcreate -L 76G -n cryptroot MorArchy
```

I'm trying to install Arch Linux with LVM and LUKS. Here's the output of vgdisplay (sorry can't really copy and paste):

[image: vgdisplay]

Am I doing something wrong here?

EDIT: The volume group is using /dev/sda3, which is 78 GB. I made sure that it was indeed using /dev/sda3.

EDIT: The output of pvdisplay (and fdisk -l):

[image: pvdisplay]

Comment: You are trying to create a 76G logical volume in a volume group that is about 2G in size. That isn't going to fit. Look at 'VG Size' and also 'Free PE / Size'. You need to make the Volume Group a lot bigger.

Comment: Your volume group only has <2.00GiB available to it. You need to increase the space available in your volume group by adding more physical volumes.

Comment: What does `pvdisplay` output?

Comment: @TorinCarey I now edited the question to have pvdisplay's output

Comment: Does running `pvresize /dev/sda3` change the `PV Size` attribute in `pvdisplay`?

Comment: @TorinCarey No. I just ran the command, it didn't change PV Size

Comment: @TorinCarey When I try to run that command, it asked me whether I wanted to proceed resizing it to 78.92 PiB. Is that supposed to happen? 78.92 PiB?

Comment: My bad, try `pvresize --setphysicalvolumesize 80818 /dev/sda3`

Comment: @TorinCarey This is what happens after resizing and trying to create the volume: https://imgur.com/gsXUlzz

Comment: Does `partprobe /dev/sda` change the size of sda3 according to the output of `fdisk -l`? If not, try `pvresize /dev/sda3` once again.

Comment: @TorinCarey I tried that command, and then did pvcreate all over again (after restarting), and it works now

Answer (score 2):

Your volume group only has 511 physical extents in total (each being 4MIBs totals just under 2GIBs.) You don't have enough free space in the volume group for the logical volume you're trying to create of 76GIBs (19456 physical extents).

You may have created the volume group on top of the wrong partition(s) if you're expecting at least 76GIBs to be available.